# Using thrift to mix development languages

Tags: php, web-services, thrift

I am currently developing an application which will require multiple different development languages. I want to use PHP as the final piece of the puzzle - the physical web page construction. This PHP web app will need to contact multiple web services which could be coded in anything from Java to Erlang to Python. Each of these web services will be implemented with an API. My plan is to use Thrift to allow this mix to work. Is this the correct approach or am I mixing up what the whole point of Thrift is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that sounds about right - [Thrift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrift_(protocol)) is one example of a serialization and RPC protocol which is implemented on multiple platforms. So long as there are bindings for all the platforms you're interested in (or you're willing to write such bindings) that should be fine. All the platforms you mentioned are already supported, so you're off to a good start.

Did you have any specific concerns, or were you just checking that you'd got the right basic idea?

Comment: just checking i had the right idea. Didn't want to go off down a route if i was mixing up what the point of thrift was. Thanks very much!